# Python - Plot density curve of two columns in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, plotly-dash

I have a dataframe with two columns "NumInstances" and "Value". I want to plot one column vs the other to see if it is normally distributed or skewed.

I have plotted a histogram of this data, however now I would like to apply a density curve on this histogram.

```
    fig = px.histogram(df
                        , nbins=30
                        , y = dff['NumInstances']
                        , x = dff['Value']
                       , histnorm='probability density' )
```

I have tried

```
    fig = px.histogram(df
                        , nbins=30
                        , y = dff['NumInstances']
                        , x = dff['Value']
                        , histnorm='probability density'
                        , density=True)
```

However this is throwing the following error (using Dash)

TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'density'

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in the parameters of the histogram method, refer [here](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html#:%7E:text=If%20%27density%27%2C%20the,into%20that%20bin.)

And it doesn't look like there's any such argument 'density'.

I think what you need to do is pass: `histnorm="density"` instead of: `histnorm="probability density"`